# JQuery * (all elements) selector excluding span tags that have some class. How could I make this work?

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors, dom-events

This is the first code

```
var operations = 0;
$('body').bind('DOMCharacterDataModified, DOMNodeInserted, DOMSubtreeModified', 'test', function() {
    if (operations < 1) {
        tba_highlight_numbers();
    }
    operations++;
});
```

And, here is the latest code of "tba_highlight_numbers" function.

```
function tba_highlight_numbers() {

//Highlighting the number on webpage.
$("body *:not(span.tba_phone)").replaceText(/\d*[/\(-]*[0-9][0-9][0-9][/ \)\(-]*[0-9][0-9][0-9][/ \)\(-]*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][/ \) ]*/g, function(ss) {
    return '<span class="tba_phone" title="Make a Call to (' + $.trim(ss) + ') via ACT Browser Applet" style="color:green" rel="' + $.trim(ss) + '">' + ss + '</span>';
});

}
```

This js code performs an operation of highlighting the phone numbers on web page. But as you can see in first part, This function is called as many times data is modified on web page dynamically via ajax request and other methods.

So, My aim is to not perform operations on previously highlighted one.

Can somebody help me in achieving this.

Comment: would it make sense to add a class to everything that has been highlighted and exclude that from subsequent calls.

Comment: Yes, I do not want to highlight the text again once highlighted.

Comment: This will select everything `$('body *').not('span.someClass')` but `span.someClass`.

Comment: not working sheikh. You can try this code executing on google search result page with query "Miami roofing". Actually, I'm developing a chrome extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function to

```
function tba_highlight_numbers() {

    //Highlighting the number on webpage.
    $("body *:not(span.tba_phone)").filter(function(){ return $(this).hasClass(".already-hightlighted");}).replaceText(/\d*[/\(-]*[0-9][0-9][0-9][/ \)\(-]*[0-9][0-9][0-9][/ \)\(-]*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][/ \) ]*/g, function(ss) {
        return '<span class="tba_phone" title="Make a Call to (' + $.trim(ss) + ') via ACT Browser Applet" style="color:green" rel="' + $.trim(ss) + '">' + ss + '</span>' + ss;
    });
    $("body *:not(span.tba_phone)").addClass('already-highlighted');


}
```

Comment: syntax error in your code. My editor is showing. Also not working BTW.

Comment: fixed... I'm assuming the replaceText is from a separate plugin.

Comment: Well, Your code was not working as provided but you did gave me a hint to achieve my target. Very much thankful to you.

Comment: what did you end up doing and I'll update my answer for the next guy